# How can I find out our civicrm sitekey?

Tags: civicrm.settings.php

I need to find out the sitekey for our developers. Not sure where to find this. Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

It's found in `civicrm.settings.php` and will be generated by the installer (or set manually depending on how your CiviCRM instance was configured).  You're looking for a line that looks like this:

```
define( 'CIVICRM_SITE_KEY', "your.site.key.is.here");
```

Comment: If this answers your question @user8161 please mark it as the accepted answer - otherwise let us know by editing your question to provide more detail.